# Предупреждение при установке Gulp.js

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm

Пытаюсь установить локально Gulp.js через npm (версии 3.3.12), при помощи следующих команд:

```
npm init
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

При установке получаю предупреждение

> npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0.

После этого в папке `node_modules` вместо папки `gulp` получаю кучу других папок.

Как исправить? Как правильно обновить версию lodash?

Comment: Это версия `lodash`, которую использует `gulp` внутри себя? Или вы сами используете `lodash 1.0.2`? Вообще, сообщение о том что пакет `deprecated` никак не влияет на его установку и работу, вы по прежнему можете им пользоваться, это просто предупреждение о том, что пакет считается устаревшим и скорее всего больше не поддерживается.

Comment: А зачем вам устанавливать gulp локально? Ставьте с -g и забейте на варнинги

Comment: Это версия 'lodash', которую использует 'Gulp'. 'Gulp' вроде работает, но некоторые плагины стали выдавать ошибки при установке.

Comment: Какую версию `npm` используете? Ну и `package.json` неплохо было бы приложить, а заодно и то, как именно вы устанавливаете Gulp и его версию.

Comment: @Dmitriy Версия `npm` 3.3.12.  `package.json` создавал с помощью `npm init`. `gulp` устанавливаю как `npm install --save-dev gulp`

Comment: @M.Tukai, отлично. А какие плагины выдают ошибки при  установке?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev `browser-sync` , `gulp-sass` , `gulp-imagemin`

Comment: @M.Tukai, а сообщения об ошибках?))

Comment: @M.Tukai, собственно, я почти на 100% уверен, что проблемы с плагинами **совсем не связаны** с предупреждением о deprecated зависимости.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev просто раньше не было ни предупреждений, ни ошибок и все отлично устанавливалось и работало. Чуть позже попробую найти пакет, с deprecated зависимостями.

Comment: По всей видимости автор lodash просто пометил версии < 3.0.0 как deprecated. Это нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ситуация, когда какой-то из npm пакетов использует deprecated зависимости периодически встречается. А происходит это из-за того, что разработчики пакета по каким-то причинам не обновляют зависимости.

На самом деле, бояться deprecated пакетов не нужно. Этот статус всего лишь означает, что пакет (или его мажорная версия) скоро перестанет поддерживаться. Сама же deprecated версия никуда не исчезнет и ей вполне можно пользоваться (конечно если вы готовы мириться с ошибками, которые никто не будет исправлять).

Что вам нужно сделать:

1. Убедиться, что все работает
2. Найти пакет с deprecated зависимостями, связаться с его автором и описать ситуацию.

Ничего самостоятельно вам обновлять не нужно. Более того, вы просто не сможете нормально это сделать, поскольку не являетесь автором/коммитером проблемного пакета.

Тот факт, что каталог `node_modules` содержит в себе не только каталог `gulp` а еще кучу всего, объясняется подходом, использованным в `npm@3`. Для снижения объема зависимостей npm избавляется от дублей, помещая их как можно выше в дереве каталогов. Вложенные зависимости используются, только тогда, когда есть конфликт версий.

Теперь несколько слов о нахождении пакета с "протухшими" зависимостями. Сам Gulp **не зависит** от lodash напрямую. К счастью, команда `npm ls` строит полное дерево зависимостей проекта, из которого вы можете понять, какой из пакетов использует `lodash@1.0.2`.