# Установка зависимостей gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp

При использовании команды `npm i gulp --save dev` выдаёт warn.

Лог:

```
d:\Projects\xampp\htdocs\boo>npm i gulp --save-dev
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Pleas
```

Подскажите, как это исправить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Предупреждение при установке Gulp.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/469673/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-gulp-js)

Comment: Если коротко - забейте. Warn - это не ошибка

Comment: Кроме того, там же прямым текстом написано, что нужно обновить пакеты. Как вариант - просто обновить что просит.

Comment: @MedvedevDev 99%, что протухшие версии не в package.json, а в зависимостях. А если это так, ТС ничего не сможет обновить сам (без помощи мейнтейнера пакета с протухшей зависимостью)